# How can I access the 'this' in a read.onloadend in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, upload

I'm trying to read a file that the user uploads in a React component and set the state of the React component to the file contents. However, in the `read.onloadend` callback function, I can't access the state through `this`.

Here is the actual form part (I am using react-bootstrap)

```
      <FormGroup>
          <FormControl
            id="fileUpload"
            type="file"
            accept=".txt"
            onChange={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
          />
      </FormGroup>
```

And here is my function to handle submit:

```
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let inputtext;
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    let read = new FileReader();
    read.readAsBinaryString(file);
    read.onloadend = function(){
      this.setState({filetext : read.result});
    }
    read.onloadend.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: please check working example to here https://codepen.io/santoshshinde2012/pen/XZwgLJ

Comment: If following answers solves your problem, please mark anyone as accepted and upvote. So that people can go ahead and solve other's questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use an arrow function. 
That way `this` will not change.

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let inputtext;
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    let read = new FileReader();
    read.readAsBinaryString(file);
    read.onloadend = () => {
      this.setState({filetext : read.result});
    }
  }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

Comment: Thank you! This was perfect! Arrow function was simplist solution.

Answer (score 1):

It fails in the onload callback due to changed context (`this`). JavaScript natively change the context in callback. In your case in onload this is the same as reader.

**Solution1**: Use [arrow operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) (`() =>`).

**Solution2**: Assign `that` variable in parent scope of `this`.

Use following code

```
  read.onloadend = () => {
    this.setState({filetext : read.result});
  }
```

OR

```
   handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault()

      // assign parent scope to here
      let that =  this;

      let inputtext;
      let file = e.target.files[0];
      let read = new FileReader();
      read.readAsBinaryString(file);

      read.onloadend = function(){
        that.setState({filetext : read.result});
      }
      read.onloadend.bind(this);
    }
```

Please check the working example to [here](https://codepen.io/santoshshinde2012/pen/XZwgLJ).

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have access to **this** inside. You have to implement it in following way.

```js
handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        let _this = this;
        let inputtext;
        let file = e.target.files[0];
        let read = new FileReader();
        read.readAsBinaryString(file);
        read.onloadend = function(){
            _this.setState({filetext : read.result});
            console.log(read.result);
        }

        read.onloadend.bind(this);
    }
```

```html
<FormGroup>
    <FormControl
        id="fileUpload"
        type="file"
        accept=".txt"
        onChange={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
    />
</FormGroup>
```